# JQuery syntax error unrecognized expression

Tags: php, jquery

```
$("#EMPLOYEE_ALT option:[value='"+$("#EMPLOYEE_ID").val()+"']").remove();
```

the above code gives the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #EMPLOYEE_ALT\ option:[value='9999']

`9999` is employee id witch is correct and this value suppose to be sent via ajax and return with something.

```
$.post("url", { emp: $("#EMPLOYEE_ID").val(),ajax: "yes"  },
```

Comment: Seems TYPO, voting to close

Comment: typographical  error :- you have unexpected : with your selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unexpected `:` in your selector. The correct selector would be

```
$("#EMPLOYEE_ALT option[value='"+$("#EMPLOYEE_ID").val()+"']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"#EMPLOYEE_ALT option[value='"+$("#EMPLOYEE_ID").val()+"']"
```

The [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) doesn't haves `:` on it. That is used for [CSS's pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) only.

```js
$("#remove").on("click", function() {
    $("#EMPLOYEE_ALT option[value='9999']").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="EMPLOYEE_ALT">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="9999">9999</option>
</select>

<button id="remove">Remove item '9999'</button>
```